# PHP CURL - как составить конструкцию?

Tags: php, curl

Как в PHP перевести вот такую конструкцию в запрос Curl?

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAM_TOKEN}" \
    -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" \
    -o speech.raw \
    --data-urlencode "text=Привет мир" \
    -d "voice=zahar&emotion=good&folderId=${FOLDER_ID}&format=lpcm&sampleRateHertz=48000" \
    https://pi.cloud.net/speech/tts:synthesize > speech.ogg
```

Не могу разобраться как указывается --data-urlencode

У меня получилось вот пока вот так:

```
$folder_id = '23232312ASdgf43';
 $url_tts = 'https://pi.cloud.net/speech/tts:synthesize';
    $data_tts = "voice=zahar&emotion=good&format=lpcm&sampleRateHertz=48000&folderId=$folder_id";
    $authorization_cloud = "Authorization: Bearer ".$iam_token;
    $headers[] = $authorization_cloud;
    $headers[] = 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';

    $ch = curl_init($url_tts);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_tts);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
$folder_id = '23232312ASdgf43';
$url_tts = 'https://pi.cloud.net/speech/tts:synthesize';

$authorization_cloud = "Authorization: Bearer " . $iam_token;
$headers[] = $authorization_cloud;
$headers[] = 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
$arrdata = array(
    'voice' => 'zahar',
    'emotion' => 'good',
    'format' => 'lpcm',
    'sampleRateHertz' => '48000',
    'folderId' => $folder_id,
    'text' => 'Привет мир',
    );
$ch = curl_init($url_tts);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($arrdata));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Пробовал. Не заработало.

Comment: можно и без http_build_query

Answer (score 0):

Вот так заработало.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$text = curl_escape($ch, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_tts);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "voice=zahar&emotion=good&folderId=$folder_id&format=lpsm&sampleRateHertz=48000&text=$text");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```